# Undefined scope after ldap search PHP

Tags: php, authentication, web, ldap

I want to receive through LDAP the user's givenname (displayname also).

I am using the following code:

```
$ldap = ldap_connect("ldap://domain.com");
        ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
        ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
        if ($bind = ldap_bind($ldap, $myusername, $mypassword)) 
        {
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;
            $filter = "(sAMAccountName={$myusername})";
            $ldap_dn = "dc=domain, dc=com";
            $attr = array("givenname");
            $result = ldap_search($ldap, $ldap_dn, $filter, $attr) or exit("Unable to search LDAP server");
            $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
            $givenname = $entries[0]['givenname'][0];
            ldap_unbind($ldap);

            setcookie("name", $givenname, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");  

            setcookie("sessao", $local, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 dia
            //header("location: welcome.php");

        }
```

Whenever I login, in the welcome page, the cookie "name" is empty, so I removed the redirect to see what is happening.

Now I am receiving the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp\www\OperPHP\authentication.php on line 21
```

Observation: Line 21 is:

```
$givenname = $entries[0]['givenname'][0];
```

I guess is something in my LDAP query, but I don't know where it could be.

Anyone could help?

@EDIT

When I use `echo print_r($entries);` it shows `Array ( [count] => 0 ) 1` ! Which means my `$entries` is not receiving any value.

Comment: What does `echo print_r($entries);` return?

Comment: It shows `Array ( [count] => 0 ) 1` ! I don't quite understand what this means...

Comment: That probably means there is something wrong in your code. You are trying to get `$entries[0]['givenname'][0]` but the only thing you would be abled to obtain out of this variable is `$entries['count']` (the only thing this array exists of) which would return `0`.

Comment: Yes, but I already looked through dozens of questions about this subject and for everyone this script works, I don't know what I am missing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your filter is quirky. From what I read there your filter actually looks this for a user with username janedoe:

```
(sAMAccountName={janedoe})
```

I'd remove the curly brackets and see whether it then works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, with it I could solve my problem. I overlooked this line of the code and found that I was concatenating the username with `@domain.com` to succesfully login and because of that it wasn't finding any result in my search. Therefore I created another variable to concatenate and I removed the `@domain.com` of `$myusername`, working fine after that!!